# Change name of Android project on Github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have a single Github **repo** that contains 5 Android **projects**. Say one of the projects is named ToysGift and I want to change that project name to ToyDrive. How do I do that?

I am using Android Studio. Can I just change the name of the project in Android Studio and then push to Github? Git always proves challenging for me that's why I am asking first before trying different things because once I break what I have, I won't know how to get back to a good git state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick test, Just changing the project name in android studio and then pushing should work, just make sure you have everything pulled so there aren't any conflicts.